# Memory Leak using Property List / NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, sprite-kit, property-list

I'm using a Property List in my main bundle to store information about the levels and player. The pList gets copied over to the phone the first time the app is launched, then I access the information as needed from that local copy. I'm running Leaks in Instruments, and I keep coming across memory leaks that I believe are related to creating the dictionary and other data types stored in the pList.

Here's where the dictionary is created - after finding the path to the pList:

```
if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path.path) {

    if let dictionaryForPlist = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOf: path) {

        return(dictionaryForPlist)
    }
    else {
        print("pList not found")
    }

let levelInstanceData = LevelData() //this class searches the main bundle for the plist and stores the pList as an NSMutableDictionary
let currentLevel = levelInstanceData.localDataFile["Level1"] as! Int //localDataFile is the NSMutableDictionary storing the information
let levelName = levelInstanceData.localDataFile["Level1Name"] as! String
```

I forcefully cast each piece of data to the correct data type and use it throughout the level.

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the leaked objects in Instruments. Has anyone else had this issue or have any ideas how to stop the leaks?

Comment: There are several questions about memory leaks on the Apple SpriteKit forums. This is the first I've seen with dictionaries. You might be lucky. The first to find this one. SK and bugs....

Answer (score 1):

Providing all the leaked objects isn't overly helpful. What you will need to do is look at the call tree related to each leaked object. This will show you where in code the leak has originated from. And from there you can start to deduce what needs to be done to remedy it.

You should read this. It is dated, but it discusses the call tree.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/instruments-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-debug-memory-leaks

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, but I'm not sure there's anything I can do about some of these leaks - a lot of them originate from `if let dictionaryForPlist = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOf: path) {` and several are from appending to arrays and setting up playSoundFileNamed actions.

Comment: Someone is still holding onto the dictionary created by `if let dictionaryForPlist = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOf: path)`. You could, as a test, have the callers of the method that get the plist copy the dictionary. Anyways, without a call tree, it is all speculation. You are going to need to better understand how retained objects work as well as how to deduce this. It is your code base so an external can't see what you see.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I'm beginning to get the hang identifying the retention cycles and have removed lots of them, but apparently not all of them. I didn't see the retention path for this, but I'll look into it again. I'll also try to grab a screenshot of one of the call trees and post it in the question.

Comment: An update to this issue - The memory leak happens on a device running iOS10, but not one running iOS9. That should mean that it's not my code that's causing the memory leak, right?